# Create an update function

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create an update function using lazy evaluation and the mutate_if function from [dplyrExtras](https://github.com/skranz/dplyrExtras) by skranz.

It would work something like this:

```
data %>%
  update(variable1_original = variable1_update,
         variable2_original = variable2_update)
```

would be evaluated as

```
data %>%
  mutate_if(!is.na(variable1_update), 
            variable1_original = variable1_update) %>%
  mutate_if(!is.na(variable2_update),
            variable2_original = variable2_update) %>%
  select(-variable1_update, variable2_update)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes, that package isn't very fun to use. `mutate_if` doesn't seem to work with data.frames and the package doesn't have standard-evaluation alternatives for functions like standard dplyr does.  Here's an attempt to re-create the function

```
myupdate <- function(.data, ...) {
    dots <- as.list(substitute(...()))
    dx <- Reduce(function(a,b) {
        upd <- b[[1]]
        ifc <- bquote(!is.na(.(upd)))
        do.call("mutate_if", c(list(a, ifc), b))
    }, split(dots, seq_along(dots)), .data)
    select_(dx, .dots=sapply(dots, function(x) bquote(-.(x))))
}
```

To test it, i used

```
library(data.table)
dd<-data.table(
   a = c(1:3, NA, 5:8)+0,
   b = c(1:2, NA, 4:5, NA, 7:8)+100,
   x= 1:8+20,
   y=1:8+30
)
dd
#     a   b  x  y
# 1:  1 101 21 31
# 2:  2 102 22 32
# 3:  3  NA 23 33
# 4: NA 104 24 34
# 5:  5 105 25 35
# 6:  6  NA 26 36
# 7:  7 107 27 37
# 8:  8 108 28 38
```

and then I ran

```
myupdate(dd, x=b, y=a)
#      x  y
# 1: 101  1
# 2: 102  2
# 3:  23  3
# 4: 104 34
# 5: 105  5
# 6:  26  6
# 7: 107  7
# 8: 108  8
```

Notice how columns "a" and "b" disappear. Also see how values in rows 3 and 6 in column "x" and the value in row 4 in column "y" was preserved because the corresponding values in columns "b" and "a" were NA.

Comment: Works perfectly! That was fast!

Comment: Although it seems like there is an issue with grouped data_frames:

dd = dd %>%
   as_data_frame %>%
   group_by(x) %>%
   myupdate(x=b, y=a)
Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : object 'INDEX.ROW__' not found

Comment: Does it work with the standard `mutate_if` syntax? Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes, same error. I guess it's a problem with mutate_if.

Comment: That would be my guess, because this function should behave exactly the same as calling `mutate_if`. You may want to submit a bug report with your test `mutate_if` code to the package author.

Comment: I also get this object 'INDEX.ROW__' not found error with a grouped DF.